# Print to server screen in socket

Tags: ruby, sockets

Is there any reason why the server process does not give any output in the following code?

```
require 'socket'

server = TCPServer.open(3000)
loop{
    puts "waiting for connection"
    client = server.accept
    puts "connection!"
    client.close
    puts "client closed"
}
```

I connect via:

```
nc localhost 3000
```

in a windows cygwin environment.

No output is visible in the server terminal. Should I maybe flush something somewhere?

Comment: solved, see comment to Sirupsens answer.

Answer (score 0):

You expect the server to respond to the client with "connection!", is that correct? If so, your problem is that `#puts` redirects its output to `STDOUT` when called on `Kernel`. If we call `#puts` on the client's `TCPSocket`, it would write the output to the `TCPSocket` IO:

```
require 'socket'

server = TCPServer.open(3000)
loop{
    puts "waiting for connection"
    client = server.accept
    client.puts "connection!"
    client.close
    puts "client closed"
}
```

And then the clients end would look like this:

```
$ nc localhost 3000
connection!
```

Comment: No, I ment for all the output to go to the server terminal. It looks like it's something with cygwin not printing to terminal before I interrupt the server process. Running in a native windows terminal gives the desired output. Thanks for the answer though.